# In Fallout Shelter, do the stats of the parents affect the baby's?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In Fallout Shelter, do the stats of the parents affect the baby's?

E.g. If both parents have a high strength stat, will the baby have one too?

Answer (score 5):

The stat that is the highest on average between the two parents determines what will be the baby's highest stat, it doesn't determine how high that stat will be though.

The highest a child can have will be 3 in any one stat.